# XSLT Data Map with the character < in the data

Tags: wcf, xslt, biztalk

I'm writing an XSLT data map from one XML schema to another XML schema. The target schema has a String field that will have a copy of the original XML in it. I know that I must convert the control characters in the XML to `&lt;` and `&gt;`. I have done that. The issue I'm having is that the data in the XML also has `&lt;` and `&gt;` in it as well. This causes problems because I'm sending the XML to a WCF-SQL adapter and when it hits the `&lt;` in my data it attempts to convert that to `<` causing XML validation failure.

Here is a snippet of my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="serialize">
    <xsl:text>&lt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="serialize"/>
    <xsl:text>&lt;/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    <xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <proc_Insert xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedProcedures/dbo">
      <StagingXML>
        <xsl:variable name="nodestring">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="serialize"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$nodestring"/>
      </StagingXML>
    </proc_Insert>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I should also mention that this is running  through BizTalk 2009, so I'm limited to XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to quote the content, a truely ancient bit of code (predating xslt 1.0 I think:-) that does that is to be found

http://www.openmath.org/cdfiles2/xsl/verb.xsl

although there are newer versions around as well/

Comment: It isn't the tags that is giving me the problem. It is the data inside thet tags. One of the bits of data looks like this: `&lt; 3 Years` and the WCF-SQL adapter converts that to  `< 3 Years`. I don't think that sample will handle that situation, would it?

Comment: Yes the referenced stylesheet goes through the data content and double quotes the characters. If you are writing your tags as &lt;foo  then you need to write that as &amp;lt; 3, which the verb.xsl will do for you